# How many secret levels are there and how do I unlock them?

Tags: tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2

I know there's at least one secret level,  but I've been having a lot of trouble figuring out  if there's any other secret levels. My google-fu is failing me, since any search for "Secret levels" just brings up details on the secret characters.

How many secret levels are there, and how do I unlock them?

Comment: Do you mean secret areas, like the spot you have to jump over a sand pit to get to in Venice Beach, the room in the Hangar you have to jump the pipe to open, etc?

Comment: @l3l_aze No, I'm referring to secret levels where levels refers to levels such as Warehouse, School II, Roswell, et cetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two secret levels, Chopper Drop and Skate Heaven.

In my playthough, I just 100% everything starting with THPS 1 then THPS 2 with one skater which seems to unlock them both.

It seems the only requirement really is to get gold medals in all 3 competitions for THPS 2. That means, get gold for Marseille, Skatestreet, and The Bullring.